# How to change the css that comes from the nuget packages?

Tags: asp.net-core

My blazor project uses mudbblazor - a third component library which I am referencing as a nuget package and here is the link to css in my index.html code

```
<link href="_content/MudBlazor.ThemeManager/MudBlazorThemeManager.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

How ever i find I wanted to make some changes to the .css file but unable to find the location of the file. How can I make changes to this file and repush it again?

Comment: Have to tried to [`implement any CSS Isolation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which can override your existing CSS in the component.  [`Please refer to this official document for details implementation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-7.0)